# Excel - Pivot Table - Formula Sum a cell only if other cell fulfill an specific value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table

I trying to create a Pivot Table on Excel with certain formulas. One of them should `sum(montant emission) only if off/online = 'OFFLINE'`

[image]

For example if I group by `Code agent`, I only want to `sum(Montant emission) if 'Off/Online' = 'OFFLINE'`

In this case the sum for `Code agent = CHO` should be `0` and for `Code agent = JGR` should be `137.5`

I need to create a formula that do this calculation. Which formula should I use on "Calculated Field"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
=SUMIF(I:I,"OFFLINE",E:E)
```

assuming that I is your Off/Online column, E is the column with the value you want to sum up.

You can also make "OFFLINE" dynamic and refer to another cell.